Insert missing time and add values to avoid gaps/spikes - Postgres
I have a file with meter consumption values received every 30 minutes/ hourly from different plants. This file gets inserted into database and I calculate the consumption based on reading value from consecutive readings:
SELECT serial_no, facility, reading, event_timestamp FROM public.meter_messages 
WHERE logical_address = '10DFFC0D37AD:1' 
ORDER BY event_timestamp


"serial_no" "facility"  "reading"   "event_timestamp"
"ABC/230121840267"  "UKSTO" 2932731.322000  "2024-03-28 14:12:16"
"ABC/230121840267"  "UKSTO" 2953866.051000  "2024-03-29 11:21:56"
"ABC/230121840267"  "UKSTO" 2954368.911000  "2024-03-29 11:51:56"
"ABC/230121840267"  "UKSTO" 2954875.512000  "2024-03-29 12:21:56"
"ABC/230121840267"  "UKSTO" 2954875.512000  "2024-03-29 12:21:56"

--Calculation difference

select date_trunc('hour', event_timestamp) as time,
(CASE WHEN reading - lag(reading) OVER ( ORDER BY event_timestamp asc) > 0 
    THEN reading - lag(reading) OVER (ORDER BY event_timestamp asc)
    ELSE 0 END) as consumption 
from public.meter_messages
WHERE serial_no = 'ABC/230121840267'


"event_timestamp_local" "consumption"
"2024-03-28 14:00:00"   400
"2024-03-29 11:00:00"   21134.729000
"2024-03-29 11:00:00"   502.860000
"2024-03-29 12:00:00"   506.601000
"2024-03-29 12:00:00"   0
"2024-03-29 12:00:00"   509.177000
"2024-03-29 13:00:00"   506.236000
"2024-03-29 13:00:00"   502.720000

* That '0' is not an issue. Sometimes the reading is received with 0 value. If I calculate daily, it doesn't create issues

The issue is that sometimes there are gaps in the timeframe, can be just a few hours during the day or days because during the weekends , meter can be off.  If I send this query to Grafana , it will show a spike for missing time between reading.
"event_timestamp_local" "consumption"
"2024-03-28 14:00:00"   400
"2024-03-29 11:00:00"   21134.729000

What I need is a query to generate hourly / 30 minutes between the min date and max date selected, with a value like average:
"event_timestamp_local" "consumption"
"2024-03-28 14:00:00"   400
"2024-03-28 15:00:00"   500
"2024-03-28 16:00:00"   500
"2024-03-28 17:00:00"   500
    .
    .
    .
    .
"2024-03-29 13:00:00"   502.720000

enter image description hereThis is what I am trying to avoid
How to plot daily increment data from a sparse data set with interpolation in Grafana?
Not successful
The ideal situation is to generate the hours 15:00 , 16:00 and calculate the increment. Average will not be that good.
"event_timestamp_local" "reading"      "consumption
"2024-03-28 11:00:00"   100
"2024-03-28 12:00:00"   180               80
"2024-03-28 13:00:00"   250               70
**"2024-03-28 14:00:00"   290               40               
"2024-03-28 17:00:00"   410               120**
"2024-03-28 18:00:00"   500               90
"2024-03-28 19:00:00"   550               50

expected data
"2024-03-28 11:00:00"   100
"2024-03-28 12:00:00"   180               80
"2024-03-28 13:00:00"   250               70
"2024-03-28 14:00:00"   290               40
**"2024-03-28 15:00:00"  320              52
"2024-03-28 16:00:00"   370               52**               
"2024-03-28 17:00:00"   410               120
"2024-03-28 18:00:00"   500               90
"2024-03-28 19:00:00"   550               50

I've got 320 at 15:00pm by adding the previous value: ~290 + (550 - 290) / 5 ~
For H 16:00 = 320 + (550 - 290)/5 ~
5 is from the nr. of hours between 15pm and 19pm.

Use generate_series() to create all the timeframes and LEFT JOIN your data to these timeframes.

What consumption do you want to fill the missing hours in with?

Please provide everything we need to understand your problem. Any ambiguity makes it difficult to answer. Complete test data and complete expected results based on that data. Ideally we should be able to create your table, insert your test data, and design a query that exactly replicates your expected results. If you set it all up in dbfiddle for us that will make answering even easier.

For 1500, 1600, and 1700 your "reading" and "consumption" do not add up. 320 - 290 is 30 not 52. 370 - 320 is 50 not 52. 410 - 370 is 40 not 120. You still have a spike at 1700. Total consumption is 554, higher than the highest meter reading of 550. Instead of averaging between 1900 and 1400, should you be averaging just the gap between 1700 and 1400?

Yes, averaging the gap values would be good, as only real data should show me a spike in consumption, but how can I generate those values to calculate AVG ?

@SamAllium Ok, then please edit your question to clearly and unambiguously show us what you want. A create table statement, sample data, and your expected results using that sample data.
